# How can I determine the IP of a remote host in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, ip, ping, parsing

I have an IP alias that switches between two hosts depending on the host's availability.  (This is a very large network and the switch is done externally of local control.)  I need to determine when the alias has switched hosts, and I can do this by detecting the IP address returned via `ping` and keeping it in state.

How can I parse the output of `ping` to retrieve just the IP address?

```
$ ping -c 1 -w 1 somehost
PING somehost (1.2.3.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from somehost (1.2.3.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.35 ms

--- somehost ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 2ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.354/1.354/1.354/0.000 ms
```

Comment: What is actually changing when the hosts fail over? Is the IP address moving to a new host? Or is the hostname changing to resolve to a different IP address?

Comment: @Kenster the latter – alias resolving to different IP

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is with `grep`:

```
$ ping -c 1 -w 1 somehost \
    | grep -oP "bytes from [A-Za-z\.]+ (\(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\))" \
    | grep -oP "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+"
1.2.3.4
```

Comment: I am very curious though -- can this answer be improved? It seems odd to me that I must use two calls to `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is with both `grep` and `sed`:

```
$ ping -c 1 -w 1 somehost \
  | grep "bytes from" \
  | sed 's/^.*(\(.*\)).*$/\1/'
1.2.3.4
```

This variant just parses out whatever is in the parenthesis on the first `bytes from` line.